# Synaptic and Software Centre Segmentation fault

Tags: software-center, synaptic, segmentation-fault

Synaptic windows disappear after a few seconds when opened. This happens also for the Software Center. On running from the terminal it gives me this phrase "Segmentation fault" how can I fix that?

Comment: I started getting this today with Chromium. Feels like an odd coincidence.

Comment: This should be filed as a bug report: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: I have been having the same problem ever since a recent update, of which chromium was one of the things updated. Bottom line. I am left with a system that cannot be upgraded or updated.

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a **segmentation fault**:

*A segmentation fault (often shortened to segfault) or bus error occurs when the hardware notifies a Unix-like operating system about a memory access violation.* (Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault))

This basically means that there's an error in the program's code, where the program tries to access a part of the computer's memory that it does not have access to. As this is a very generic error that can occur for very many reasons, it is hard for me to say the exact reason why this happens, and give you a solution.